# Linking error with luarocks

Tags: lua, lnk2019, luarocks

Im trying to use luarocks for installing luafilesystem module.
Since im trying to install version 1.6.2, luarocksis trying to build luafilesystem on my local machine.

I have the following error: **lfs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol**. I have this error for 30 standard lua functions: lua_pushinteger, lua_pushstring.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Im using:
1. Lua 5.1 for windows 7.
2. CL compiler of Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 for amd64.
3. Microsoft SDK's V6.1 for X64

Comment: Is it linking to lua5.1.dll?

Comment: lua5.1.dll is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1. This folder is part of LIB,LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH. How can i tell if luarocks linking it with this file?

Comment: the linking command is link -dll -def:lfs.def -out:"C:/LuaRocks/lib/lua/5.1/lfs.dll" C:/LuaRocks/2.1/lua5.1.lib src/lfs.obj. How can i make it use lua5.1.dll?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
I learned that luarocks uses a config file (config.lua) which contains the name of lua's lib file (lua5.1.lib). The lib file didnt fit my machine, so I took the lib file for x64 (from my lua version and switched it).

Comment: I have same problem with you. Please add more detail on how you fix it.